# Conditional Running Counts from lagged variables

Tags: python, pandas

When the `value` is `<` to `lagged_value` I would like to **subtract** 1 from the running count.

When the `value` is `=` to `lagged_value` I would like to do nothing

When the `value` is `>` to the `lagged_value` I would like to **add** 1

Here is the code I have, the variable `objective` contains the desired results, where it is an accumulating count given the criterion above.

How can I do this with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-01-05','2021-01-06','2021-01-07','2021-01-08','2021-01-09'],
                 'value':[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,3],
                 'objective':[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,2]})
df['lag_value']=df.value.shift(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the [**`cumsum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of the decrements and increments:

```py
dec = df.value.lt(df.lag_value).mul(-1)
inc = df.value.gt(df.lag_value).mul(1)
df['answer'] = dec.add(inc).cumsum()
```

```
date        value   objective   lag_value   answer
2021-01-01  1       0           NaN         0
2021-01-02  1       0           1.0         0
2021-01-03  2       1           1.0         1
2021-01-04  1       0           2.0         0
2021-01-05  2       1           1.0         1
2021-01-06  2       1           2.0         1
2021-01-07  1       0           2.0         0
2021-01-08  2       1           1.0         1
2021-01-09  3       2           2.0         2
```